# How can associate keys against secret in azure key vault?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I am new to Azure and trying to understand if there any co-relation between key and secret in azure key vault

i have below question on using key against a secret

Eg:

1. Secret with db credentials
2. Represent key for accessing secret

Is this possible in azure key-vault?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible,

You can store your DB Password in a secret and your DB user in another secret, or even store both in the same secret. At the end key vault save strings.

In Key Vault you must follow the next steps to create a secret:

1. Open the secret section and go to Generate/Import
   [image: create secret]
2. insert the Name (Key) and the secret value (value), and then create your secret
   [image: secret2]

After that, you can refer to the name to get the value of the secret
[image: secret3]

Hope this helps!